# QDir::exists with mapped remote directory

Tags: c++, qt5.3, qdir

I use `QDir::exists` to check directories. However, when the checked directory name (string) points to **mapped network directory** which is **not** available, then the function takes pretty long (up to 10secs and longer) to return.

How could I realize a shorter timeout? Or is there anything better to check?

Comment: I don't know if there's anything that can be done at the Qt level; the OS is presenting the directory as if it were a mounted hard drive, but it can't force the "hard drive" to respond in a timely manner.  You could move the I/O calls into their own separate thread, so that at least the GUI would not be frozen up during the timeout period.